# jQuery drag and drop - help needed

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop

I am dragging an element to another div and dropping it. (cloned)
I drag the same elemnt again so there are 2 same elements on the droppable div.

I click on one dropped object and it opens a dialog which I fill in and the text on the object changes.

What is happening is that both dropped elements have the same text..

My question is:

How do I differentiate betweens dropped elements so that a change to one will not affexct the other(s)

I appreciate anyones input.

Comment: Post your code in your question please.

Comment: Would a screenshot work...?
Too much code to post. :-(

Comment: No, screenshots aren't any good for us to use to debug and troubleshoot. And please post the code in your question, not as a comment. You should also work to narrow down your code example to the smallest possible example. This can also have the added benefit of helping you troubleshoot your own issue.

Comment: "Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers." - So is over moderation....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

Full Fiddle Here: https://jsfiddle.net/red2678/4vLf1usz/27/

```
// Draggable
$("#draggable").draggable({
    revert: 'invalid',
    cursor: 'move',
    helper: 'clone'
});

// Droppable
$("#droppable").droppable({
    drop: function (event, ui) {
        // $this is the dropped elements container
        // $dd is the div where the dropped elements are
        // count is the count of currently dropped divs (1 based)
        // item is a clone of the draggable element
        // -- on item I am setting the id attribute
        // -- to be the word "drop" and the count
        // -- ex: drop1, then drop2 and so on.
        var $this = $(this),
            $dd = $this.find('#droppedDivs'),
            count = $dd.find('> div').length + 1 || 1,
            $item = $(ui.draggable).clone().attr('id', 'drop' + count);

        // Change the dropped elements container h3 to show
        // the dropped count and add hightlight class
        $this.addClass("ui-state-highlight")
            .find("h3")
            .html("Dropped " + count + "!");

        // Change content of dropped div to "id is #drop" and the count
        $item.html('id is #drop' + count);

        // Append to the dropped elements container
        $dd.append($item);

        // Now all divs inside #droppedDivs have unique ids :)
    }
});
```